# Prove that a function is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove that $g(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&x\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q \end{cases}$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Please write $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ and not $R/Q$.

Answer (score 1):

I think $R/Q$ means $ \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q.$

For $x \ne 0$ we have
$$|\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}|=\frac{|g(x)|}{|x|}  \le \frac{x^2}{|x|} =|x|.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Yes thank you, that'll help.